# How to download a file with attribute(href) in chrome using selenium webdriver via js executor

Tags: selenium-webdriver

I want to download a file in Selenium web driver in C#. 
i have the url in the web element as the attribute href. With that url, i have to download the file through javascript executor. 
I tried with js executescript to get the file in the form of bytes and then converting it to pdf file and storing in my desired location. But no luck

```
IWebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("https://www.win-rar.com/predownload.html?&L=0");
string linkVal = driver.FindElement(By.LinkText("Download WinRAR")).GetAttribute("href");
var href = "https://www.win-rar.com/fileadmin/winrar-versions/winrar/winrar-x64-571.exe";
IJavaScriptExecutor js = (IJavaScriptExecutor)driver;
///  Object reposne = js.ExecuteScript("arguments[0].setAttribute(arguments[1],arguments[2])", linkVal, "href", "https://www.win-rar.com/postdownload.html?&amp;L=0");
String script = "document.querySelector('a[href*=\"/print/\"]').setAttribute('download','name-of-the-download-file-recommend-guid-or-timestamp.pdf');";
///Object reposne = js.ExecuteAsyncScript(script , href);
var bytes = Convert.FromBase64String(reposne.ToString());
File.WriteAllBytes("F:\\file.exe", bytes);
```

Comment: did you get this resolved?

Answer (score 0):

If you are just trying to download the file, all you really need is this.

```
driver.FindElement(By.Id("download-button")).Click();
```

This will save it in your default location for your browser.

or in js executor

```
WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.id("download-button"));
JavascriptExecutor executor = (JavascriptExecutor)driver;
executor.executeScript("arguments[0].click();", element);
```

To go to a specific location, try adding chrome options:

in C#

```
                ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
                options.AddArguments("--disable-extensions");
                options.AddArguments("disable-infobars");
                options.AddUserProfilePreference("download.default_directory", "My Path");
                 options.AddUserProfilePreference("profile.password_manager_enabled", false);
                options.AddUserProfilePreference("credentials_enable_service", false);
                _Driver = new ChromeDriver(@"DriverPath"), options);
                _wait = new WebDriverWait(_webDriver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10));
                _Driver.Manage().Window.Maximize();
```

as a last resort, just move the file with:

```
    public class MoveMyFile
    {
        static void Main()
        {
            string sourceFile = @"C:\My\File\Path\file.txt";
            string destinationFile = @"C:\My\New\Path\file.txt";

            // Move my file to a new home!
            System.IO.File.Move(sourceFile, destinationFile);
        }
    }
```

Comment: I should download to specific path which I provide.. In that case, how it can be handled

Comment: I want to download it to specific path which I provide.. In that case, how to handle via java script executor

Comment: ok I saw below that you could not change chrome options. How about just moving the file to where you want it after download?

Comment: I did that only.. Wrote a method to transfer file from source to destination... I did that.. But furious to know without changing chrome option how to download the file to my specified path

Answer (score 0):

I'm actually using [RestSharp](http://restsharp.org/).

Like so:

```
    public FileInfo DownloadFile(string downloadUrl)
    {
        RestClient rest = new RestClient();
        RestRequest request = new RestRequest(downloadUrl);
        byte[] downloadedfile = rest.DownloadData(request);
        string tempFilePath = Path.GetTempFileName();
        File.WriteAllBytes(tempFilePath, downloadedfile);
        return new FileInfo(tempFilePath);
    }
```

Consider not creating a rest client for each download request.
The RestClient also supports a base URL for convenience.

Hope this is what you wanted.

Comment: I need to save it to my specific path which I provided.. In that case, how it can be handled

Comment: Just make the "tempFilePath" not set from temp but passed to the function, like so:
public FileInfo DownloadFile(string downloadUrl, string downloadedFilePath)
{
        RestClient rest = new RestClient();
        RestRequest request = new RestRequest(downloadUrl);
        byte[] downloadedfile = rest.DownloadData(request);
        File.WriteAllBytes(downloadedFilePath, downloadedfile);
        return new FileInfo(downloadedFilePath);
}

Comment: I tried rest sharp, but my actual file is being corrupted. Not able to view the contents

Answer (score 0):

```
I have tested your scenario using Java, Selenium and TestNG. Where you can save the file in the root folder directory

import org.testng.annotations.Test;
import org.testng.annotations.BeforeMethod;
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeOptions;
import org.openqa.selenium.remote.DesiredCapabilities;
import org.testng.Assert;
import org.testng.annotations.AfterMethod;
import java.io.File;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.UUID;


public class FileDownload {

    File folder;
    WebDriver driver;

    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    @BeforeMethod
    public void setUp() {

        //a random folder will be created 88998-98565-09792-783727-826233
        folder = new File(UUID.randomUUID().toString());
        folder.mkdir();

        //Chrome Driver
        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "---Your Chrome Driver or chromedriver.exe URL;--");
        ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();

        Map<String, Object> prefs = new HashMap<String, Object>();

        //When you click on download, it will ignore the popups
        prefs.put("profile.default_content_settings.popups", 0);
        prefs.put("download.default_directory", folder.getAbsolutePath());
        options.setExperimentalOption("prefs", prefs);

        DesiredCapabilities cap = DesiredCapabilities.chrome();
        cap.setCapability(ChromeOptions.CAPABILITY, options);
        driver = new ChromeDriver(cap);

    }

    @Test
    public void downloadFileTest() throws InterruptedException{
        driver.get("https://www.win-rar.com/predownload.html?&L=0");
        driver.findElement(By.linkText("Download WinRAR")).click();

        /* Depending on your download speed you have to increase or decrease the sleep value, if you give less than download time it will give error as: java.lang.AssertionError: expected [true] but found [false] */
        Thread.sleep(5000);
        File listOfFiles[] = folder.listFiles();
        Assert.assertTrue(listOfFiles.length>0);

        for(File file: listOfFiles){
            Assert.assertTrue(file.length()>0);
        }
    }       

    @AfterMethod
    public void tearDown() {
        driver.quit();
        /* You can comment below "for loop": for testing purpose where you can see the folder and file download, if you uncomment it will delete the file and folder: useful for regression you wont end up having so many files in the root folder */
        for(File file: folder.listFiles()){
            file.delete();
        }
        folder.delete();
    }

}
```

Comment: I have idea in java.. I need to download via webservice or C# or java script executor

Comment: In my framework its been set to some other path.. The chrome options.i can't change that.. . For this file download alone, I wanna place my file to specific path which I give. How that can be done